# What's keeping BindingList from subscribing to the PropertyChanged event?

Tags: c#, datagridview, inotifypropertychanged

I've set my DataGridView.Source property to a `BindingList<T>`, where T implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

It's not working though, and sure enough when I step through the code I find that nothing is subscribing to the PropertyChanged event.  How do I get the BindingList to subscribe to this event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 30 minutes of searching for the answer, I would naturally figure it out on my own 5 seconds after I post my question.

I had `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented on `MyClass`, but I was actually using `BindingSource<IMyClass>` and `IMyClass` didn't inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Once I fixed that it worked.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem thanks! I want to mention that this also occurs if you create a BindingList<MyClass> where MyClass in a subclass of another class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I still had to add INotifyPropertyChanged directly to MyClass

Comment: Awesome, I love it when something I wrote years ago helps someone! :)